# My bot won't play music. Is something wrong in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I have done everything correctly according to the video and it doesn't seem to work.

I've correcting my mistakes but nothing seems to help

This is my code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

client.login(token);

const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };

client.on=('ready', () => {
    console.log("Music Bot is Ready");

});

client.on('message', Message => {
    if(Message.author.bot)
        return;
    if(Message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("?play"))
    {

        let VoiceChannnel = message.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.id === 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
        if(VoiceChannnel != null)
        {
            console.log(VoiceChannnel.name + " Was found and is a " + VoiceChannnel.type + " channel.");
            VoiceChannnel.join()
            .then(connection =>{
                console.log("Bot joined the channel!");
                const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXXXXXXXXX', { filter :'audioonly' });
                const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
            })
            .catch();
        };

    }
});
```

Music bot was found and is in a voice channel

Comment: `.catch()`  you are intentionally hiding any possible errors with this. I suggest you add something like `.catch(err => { console.error(err) })`

Comment: `client.on=('ready', () => {
    console.log("Music Bot is Ready");

});`  <-- error

Comment: Could you please also add any error messages you get in regards to the output?

Comment: As @epascarello points out, `client.on=...` is wrong but it won't trigger any errors. What you're effectively doing there is **replacing** `client.on` with a function that logs _"Music Bot is Ready"_ and does nothing else. Your next call to `client.on('message', ...` will execute that function you assigned. Long store short, remove the `=` and make it `client.on('ready', ...`

Comment: I'm have to back to you guys have to get some sleep. But thx in advance